# SQL Date parameter for report

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table

[image]

```
SELECT product
FROM table
WHERE TRY_CAST(purchased AS Date) >= ’12/02/2021’
  AND TRY_CAST(purchased AS Date) <= ’12/09/2021’
```

Running the query in SQL Server I am only getting 1 row. Date '12/09/2021' is not showing. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Date related datatypes use `YYYY-MM-DD` format. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  Use `>= '2021-12-02'` and `<= '2021-12-09'` assuming you mean Dec 2 and Dec 9

Comment: Safest format is `YYYYMMDD`. Also why do you have to convert the column to a date? Is it not stored as the right data type? See [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I figured you had a good discertation on this somewhere. Just watched [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9315/recommended-sql-server-date-formats/). I never realized that `YYYY-MM-DD` wasn't language safe...  Argh.  "This surprises a lot of people".  Yep.

Comment: I recommend a read of [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea?__=1981379712) too.

Comment: @squillman Oof, I just read that transcript, and I can't believe how often I say "so"

Comment: @AaronBertrand Haha. No ah's or um's though, so I call it a wash

Comment: @squillman :-) let me tell you, it takes years to fully transition from one bad habit to another